# Error: x and y must have same first dimension. Why?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Why do I get the error: "x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (15,) and (23,)"?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9cU4.png)

```
index = np.where(A3_Fixed == 0)[0]

for x in index:
    A2.pop(x)
    A3_Fixed.pop(x)
    A4_Fixed.pop(x)
    A5_Fixed.pop(x)
    A6_Fixed.pop(x)
plt.plot(A2, A3_Fixed, color="brown", label="Pasta In P1", marker="o")
plt.plot(A2, A4_Fixed, color="brown", linestyle=":", label="Pasta Out P1", marker="o")
plt.plot(A2, A5_Fixed, color="green", label="Líquido de Lavagem P1", marker="o")
plt.plot(A2, A6_Fixed, color="green", label="Filtrado P1", linestyle=":", marker="o")
```

Comment: You are trying to create a line plot where `y` is a value dependent on `x`, therefore for every `y` there should be a value of `x` and *vice versa*. Hence if sizes don't match you get this error.

Comment: But my data have the same number of values for x an y. Thats why I don't get it.

Comment: The error message says that one of the arrays has the length 15 and the other is 23 so your data does not have same dimensions. Check sizes of all your arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `A2` and `A3_fixed` are lists, you can ensure they are the same size by performing the following and see if your problem persists. If it does, then somehow you did not have the same number of values for your `x` and `y`, as pavel mentioned in their comment.

```
# limit both lists to the size of the smaller one
A2 = [:min(len(A2),len(A3_fixed))]
A3_fixed = [:min(len(A2),len(A3_fixed))]
```

You can also just check the lengths of each right before attempting to plot by calling `print(len(list_name))`.

Comment: When I limit lists i get an error: len() takes exactly one argument (2 given). And you are right: for some reason it says that A2 has 14 values and A3_Fixed has 23. But they both have 23 in reality

Comment: Sorry, I meant to call `len` separately on the two lists, not together. It should read `min(len(A2),len(A3_fixed))`. I have fixed it in my original reply.

Comment: And to investigate the reason for unexpected differences in length, I would recommend following these lists backwards, using print statements to see how their lengths evolve from creation to this point. Perhaps A2 is being popped from more than it should, or maybe they were different lengths from the very beginning.

Comment: Thank you. Same type of error: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (23,). I have no idea...sorry, just very recently I started programming